# Highcharts zoom on axis with min and max

Tags: plot, highcharts

I'm plotting data that will always be between 0 and 100 (on the y axis), so I've set the `yAxis` `min` and `max` properties to those respective values.

The issue is that I still would like to zoom (on the y axis) into the chart, and then when I reset the zoom it would take me back to the min and max. Can this be accomplished with Highcharts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it is possible,

you need to use zoomType property

```
chart:{
 zoomType: 'xy'
}
```

here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/PgM9w/
here is the api refernce for the same http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.zoomType

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's interesting that it only works for 'xy', it would be nice if achievable in either 'x' or 'y', but this will definitely work for now.